# flip card auto height?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am not able to find a solution to fix auto height for flip front and back card. Especially in the Firefox browser.

```js
$(".card").flip({
  axis: 'y',
  trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
}
.card .front, .card .back {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto !important;
}
.card .default{
  background-color: white;
}
.card .back{
  background-color: rgba(71, 207, 115, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flipcard.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="template">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>test content</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card"> 
              <div class="front"> 
               <p>Front</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue.  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee" class="img-responsive img-rounded width-200 center-block" /><strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor </p>

              </div> 
              <div class="back">
                <p>Back</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue.
                  <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card"> 
              <div class="front"> 
               <p>Front</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. </p>
              </div> 
              <div class="back">
                <p>Back</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="front">
                          <p>Front</p>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee" class="img-responsive img-rounded width-200 center-block" />
                  <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>test content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Above code is based JQuery and JS. In responsive mode, it is overlapping with below content.

If any solution would be more helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly clear your question a bit more. Either you want your `cards` of the same height or explain `fix auto height`.

Comment: yes, same height for front and back card...

Comment: then you need to provide the fix height

Comment: I have used the fixed height with pure CSS style. But below content is overlapping with it https://codepen.io/syed-quadri/pen/zLayJy

Comment: Also add `height: 400px;` to `.flipcard` in your css. You have only assigned height to `.front` and `.back` but not to card itself

Comment: I got the solution @thezeeshantariq, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox and rely on its default stretch property to keep both element equal height. You need to also adjust some CSS and use `!important` to override some inline style added by the JS.

```js
$(".card").flip({
  axis: 'y',
  trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```css
.card {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
}
.card .front, .card .back {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative!important;
  height:auto!important;
}
.card .front {
  margin-right:-100%;
}
.card .default{
  background-color: white;
}
.card .back{
  background-color: rgba(71, 207, 115, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flipcard.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="template">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>test content</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card"> 
              <div class="front"> 
               <p>Front</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue.  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee" class="img-responsive img-rounded width-200 center-block" /><strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor </p>

              </div> 
              <div class="back">
                <p>Back</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue.
                  <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card"> 
              <div class="front"> 
               <p>Front</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. </p>
              </div> 
              <div class="back">
                <p>Back</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="front">
                          <p>Front</p>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut non quam in nisi molestie vulputate. Etiam ornare est in ipsum elementum, nec sodales lacus congue. <img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee" class="img-responsive img-rounded width-200 center-block" />
                  <strong>Praesent non tristique arcu.</strong> Sed a viverra nulla. Nunc vehicula orci risus, a pellentesque metus hendrerit a. Duis at lorem tortor. </p>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>test content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```